# MATLAB: Read text file and split it to a multi dimensional cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, split

I have a big text file whose format is as follow:

```
M23 I13 C11 D12 A13
K15 I01 L19 D02 O15
```

I want to read the file into a matrix so that I can process the IDs one by one. Each row is independent.

For example, I want to have a matlab code that can do the same thing as the following Perl code:

```
my @AoA = map { chomp; [ split /\t/, $_ ] } <FILE>;
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: does `dlmread` work for you?

Comment: It doesn't help. The numbers of IDs in each line (row) are different.

Comment: [Perl](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/perl.html) is included in matlab, so if you dont mind using it, maybe using it would solve your problem.

Comment: Very cool~ I didn't know that. The R2012b I am using doesn't have the perl() function. I will see if I can find R2014a version. Thanks!

Comment: Older versions also should have. maybe its under different name.

Comment: Does this mean you want to keep the rows intact? So in your example you want a `{2,n}` cell array? `n=5` in this example but each row will have different number of columns in your real file..? Is that correct?

Comment: I want to process each row in a for loop. Yes, I wanted a {2,n} cell array. Yes, different number of columns. If it doesn't fit to one cell array, I just need to have a for loop to process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two suggestions, both of which produce a cell array with intact rows at the end.

First one loads the entire file into memory and then converts each variable into a cell element.
This is more compact. The disadvantage is that it keeps two copies of the dat in memory.

The second version reads the file line by line and converts each value into cell a element.
The advantage is that it requires less memory and it seems to be faster.

Timings:

1. 0.0175769 seconds.
2. 0.00976515 seconds.

0.0175769 - 0.00976515  =  0.0078117

or version 1 is

`0.0078117/0.0175769 = 0.44443` slower.

Version 1:

```
tic;
formatSpec = '%s';

fileID = fopen ('datafile.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,...            
                'Delimiter', '\n', ...
                'CollectOutput', true);

B= C{1};
D = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x, '%s'), B);
toc
D


Elapsed time is 0.0175769 seconds.
D =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = M23
    [2,1] = I13
    [3,1] = C11
    [4,1] = D12
    [5,1] = A13
  }
  [2,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = K15
    [2,1] = I01
    [3,1] = L19
    [4,1] = D02
    [5,1] = O15
  }
}
```

Version 2

```
tic;
formatSpec = '%s';

fileID = fopen ('datafile.txt');
rowNr = 1;
y=0;
C={};
tline = fgetl(fileID);
while ischar(tline)
   A = textscan(tline,formatSpec);
   C{rowNr} = A{1};

   %Check for end of file
   matches = strfind(tline, '\n');
   num = length(matches);
   if num > 0
      y = y + num;
      fprintf(1,'%d:%s\n',num,tline);
   end

   tline = fgetl(fileID);
   rowNr = rowNr+1;
end
fclose(fileID);

toc
C



Elapsed time is 0.00976515 seconds.
C =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = M23
    [2,1] = I13
    [3,1] = C11
    [4,1] = D12
    [5,1] = A13
  }
  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] = K15
    [2,1] = I01
    [3,1] = L19
    [4,1] = D02
    [5,1] = O15
  }
}
```